# Create table like this image below using react-native

Tags: react-native

I need to create a table like the image below using react-native, is there any library to create one ?

[image: Like this Image]

Comment: We don't see any image that you mentioned

Comment: Sorry, uploading problem

Comment: something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component ?